# How to create a search menu logic in backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a WebApp with `express`, `Nodejs` and `MongoDb`.
In this app i create and save articles, I wanted to add a search menu, I know how to create and style it with `html` and `css` but i don't know how to create the logic that can filter the results.

The search menu that i was thinking to make is something like the one in amazon, where you can select more options simultaneously and filter the results.

[image]

I know how to create a search engine where you can select one option at the time but i don't know how to do it for more options simultaneously.

Comment: One thing that Express offers is when the same query param is repeated, it concatenates each value onto an array, rather than overwriting the previous value. E.g., `GET /shoes?color[]=blue&color[]=black&color[]=red` → `req.query.color == ['blue', 'black', 'red']`. See [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Comment: i saw that too but i didn't understand how to add multiple query values. I tried to create some links and each one had as `href` a different query value but each time that i clicked one link the previous values were gone

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create an entire search functionality in the backend on express?

Comment: I'm trying to create a search functionality on the backand for filter some articles, like filter by title, argoument, date and other stuffs